# CSS setting a custom font

Tags: css

```
a, h1, h2, h3, div, span td[style] {font-family:'Tahoma2';} !important

@font-face {
font-family: 'Tahoma2'; 
src: url('http://***.com/font.otf') format('otf'),  !important
src: url('http://***.com/font.ttf') format('truetype');   !important
}
```

I am appending CSS to my profile page on a website, using the provided custom CSS tool, however, as I was customising various things, I discovered this problem.
When I put in the above code, all the text that SHOULD be Tahoma2, ends up as Times New Roman, which I am assuming means it is having trouble finding the font from the url (I hid the URL for privacy reasons), especially as when  I change the top line to say 'Tahoma' it sets the whole page to tahoma. Would someone please tell me where the GLARING error in my code is, as I can't find it. (BTW, I know important shouldn't be used, but I had to override the source page's CSS in a few places.)

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Sleumas

EDIT

After some more editing, I used the solution provided by Damien Overeem, but then, in the console, I got this message (firefox)

downloadable font: download not allowed (font-family: "tahoma2" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): content blocked
source: www.mysite.com/fonts/celestia.ttf

and the same for the woff

does anyone know why? is this sanitisation, or a problem with my hosting, it is on my own private apache server, just as a file in the /var/www/fonts directory

Please help!

Comment: First step would be to check your console's (firebug, chrome's ctrl+shift+c) network tab and see if your font file is actually being loaded. It could in example be that your webserver (ie microsoft IIS does this), denies the font mime types.

Comment: @DamienOvereem It's not getting Loaded by the browser. One of two things must be happening. A) The parent website is sanitising my CSS, B) I made a big error.

Comment: 1) !important on line 1 should be inside the brackets 2) do you need 2 important with that src attribute? try to remove the first one 3) place the font-face before referencing to it. 4) try without format()

Answer (score 0):

( I would normally post this as a comment, but since comment markup would mess things up, I'll have to post it as an answer )

This snippet below is what I normally use to include fonts (different types for different browsers). Perhaps this can help you.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Tahoma2';
    src: url('../fonts/Tahoma2-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Tahoma2-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Tahoma2-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Tahoma2-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Tahoma2-webfont.svg#tahoma2') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I don't have all those formats available, is there a way to convert fonts?